# How to merge more images faster?

Tags: php, image, merge

I'm working on a sprite generator and I need to merge more than two images. My problem is only that, my script is a bit slow:

```
foreach ($imageData as $i)
{
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($timg.'.png');
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($imageS[$x]);

imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_1, true); 
$magass = $magass + $imageData[$y][1];
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, $magass, 0, 0, $imageData[$x][0], $imageData[$x][1]);
                         // <-> | le
imagepng($image_1, $timg.'.png'); 
}
```

This script saves an image and merge put on my image on that image and save it. After that open it, put on the next image, save it, open put another one, save, etc... It's a very bad solution. How could I make it more better for performance. So how could I merge all with only one save?

Comment: `\`backticks\`` are for inline code only, not emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save intermediate steps. Provide a base image, anda  list of other images to merge on top. do that merging all at once in a loop, and **THEN** save the final image. right now you're loading `$source`, loading a `$merge`, overlaying, then saving the file, then shutting down all the image code. Next $merge, you repeat that all over again. e.g you're wasting a LOT of CPU cycles on useless work. Try something more like:

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($timg.'.png');
foreach($imagedata as $img) {
    merge($image_1, $img);
}
imagepng($image_1);
```

instead.You load the base image ONCE, overlay all the other images on top of it, then finally save the output.